# flutter unable to load asset with correct settings

Tags: android, flutter, dart

this is my `asset` folder structure:

[image]

`pubspec.yaml` contents:

[image]

where that I use icon:

[image]

everything is right but I don't know why still it doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Just try with flutter clean and re-run

Comment: flutter pub get and re-run.

Comment: The Main Version of Flutter Does Not Support SVG

Comment: I tried flutter clean and it's worked, thanks @JahidulIslam. but if I add a new icon do I have to do it again?

Comment: Only for the first time, you just need to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens multiple time while developing with flutter.
Steps which I usually do to solve this kind of issue:

->Restart the IDE and run pub get again (it works sometime).

->Run flutter clean, and re-run the App(It clears build cache of the App).
It worked in most of the cases.